# fork/exec . no such file or directory exit status 1

Tags: go, fork, exec

I am using Go 1.10.2 on Mac (darwin/amd64) and facing this error. It's saying no such file or directory.

Here's my code,

```
func loop1(gor_name string, ras_ip string) {
    var a string
    var c string
    a = search_path()
    fmt.Printf("当前路径为", a)
    fmt.Println(os.Chdir(a))

    c = fmt.Sprintf("%s %s %s %s", "./goreplay  --input-file ", gor_name, " --input-file-loop --output-http ", ras_ip)
    fmt.Printf("c:  ", c)
    cmd := exec.Command(c)
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    channel <- 1

}
```

Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The function signature for exec.Command is:

```
func Command(name string, args ...string) *Cmd
```

where `name` is the name of the program and `args` are the arguments. Try this:

```
cmd := exec.Command("./goreplay", "--input-file", gor_name, "--input-file-loop", "--output-http", ras_ip)
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just an information on @cerise-limon answer.

The `exec` command requires `command` and then the `arguments`.
The string of command and args will throw the same error.

Pass the command to `exec` following with the comma separated `args`.

Answer (score 0):

The other way to do is:

```
type Client struct {
    logger *logrus.Entry
}

const shell = "/bin/bash"

// Execute executes the provided command
func (c *Client) Execute(command []string) (bool, error) {

    c.logger.Info("Executing command ", shell, " -c ", strings.Join(command, " "))

    output, err := exec.Command(shell, "-c", strings.Join(command, " ")).Output()

    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

    c.logger.Info(string(output))

    return true, nil
}

func GetBashClient() *Client {
    logger := logrus.NewEntry(logrus.StandardLogger())
    return &Client{logger: logger}
}
```

Now you can call

```
command := []string{
    "/usr/bin/<your script>.sh",
    args1,
    args2
}

GetBashClient().Execute(command)
```